# How to implement the optimistic UI in the case of fe-retching a different query in Apollo v3 React client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, optimistic-ui

I'm trying to implement the Optimistic UI for the ***like*** functionality but I can't handle it because of the dedicated query I must re-fetch to update the articles.
Let me explain it a bit better via code examples:
Here is the article document I have.

[image: Article GraphQl schema]

I want to mutate the `liked` property and I have a mutation to do it:

```
  mutation LikeArticle($status: Boolean!, $articleId: String!) {
    likeArticle(status: $status, articleId: $articleId)
  }
```

to fetch the Article document I have this query:

```
  query GetArticle($id: String!) {
    getArticle(id: $id) {
      id
      createdAt
      liked
      likes

      author {
        id
        username
      }

      topics {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
```

In my UI I just render the Article document based on the data **getQuery** provides. Also, I have the **Like** button and when the user presses on it the **likeArticle** mutation executes and I must refetch the **getArticle** query to update the UI.
And here is the issue, I just want to add the optimistic UI to not to wait for the long server response however it doesn't work at all. Probably because of the **re-fetching** **getArticle** query but I'm not sure

```
  const [
    likeArticle,
    {
      data: likeArticleData,
      loading: likeArticleLoading,
      error: likeArticleError,
    },
  ] = useMutation(LIKE_ARTICLE, {
    refetchQueries: [
      {
        query: GET_ARTICLE_QUERY,
        variables: { id: article.id },
      },
    ],
    optimisticResponse: {
      getArticle: {
        id: article.id,
        __typename: "Article",
        liked: !article.liked,
      },
    },
  });
```

Example of executing **likeArticle mutation**

```
likeArticle({
  variables: {
    status: !article.liked,
    articleId: article.id,
  },
});
```

I'll appreciate any help/information

Comment: `optimisticResponse` is for current request response simulation, update can be used to update query cache entry ... but is fired after mutation response, too .... you can use `client` to update cache just after calling mutation, in event handler

Comment: I see, didn't know it. Thank you @xadm, I really appreciate your help

Comment: try `optimisticResponse: {  likeArticle: {` - `likeArticle` as it is your mutation expected data structure ... if both query and mutation are refs (in cache store) to the same object, then component based/watching on query result should be updated/rerendered ... if not, use client cache update/writeQuery

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately, the `likeArticle` mutation returns the boolean scalar type so Apollo can't determinate what object is relative to this particular mutation

Comment: make it returning Article type?

Answer (score 0):

Using `client` and `optimisticResponse` options might help in this case. Here is the [Official Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/optimistic-ui/). It's often possible to predict the most likely result of a mutation before the GraphQL server actually returns it. Apollo Client can use this likely result to update your UI optimistically, making the app feel more responsive to the user. using `client` is way ahead but it won't work in case of request failed and you want the reversal of the last optimistic action take manually. I would give priority to `optimisticResponse` over `client`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kiran but the optimistic UI doesn't work in my case at all so, unfortunately, the only way is just the client operations as @xadm mentioned